# Run a bamboo script with docker

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, bamboo

I get the following error when executing a Bamboo Script Task in a Isolate build  Docker container:

```
simple  27-Jun-2019     Starting task 'XYZ' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.scripttask:task.builder.script'
command 27-Jun-2019     Beginning to execute external process for build 'XYZ'\n ... running command line: \n/tmp/runInDocker3301468521768702357.sh /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/XYZ-8591248614821374698.sh\n ... in: /tmp\n
error   27-Jun-2019     flag provided but not defined: -e
error   27-Jun-2019     See 'docker exec --help'.
simple  27-Jun-2019     Failing task since return code of [/tmp/runInDocker3301468521768702357.sh /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/XYZ-8591248614821374698.sh] was 125 while expected 0
simple  27-Jun-2019     Finished task 'list buckets' with result: Failed
```

The configuration is similar to this link [Docker Runner](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/docker-runner-946020207.html) the following and shown here:
[image]

```
Isolate build -> Docker container -> Docker image: `ubuntu:16.04`
```

The script task is:

```
Shell -> Inline
```

with the following simple content:

```
echo "Hallo AWS"
#!/bin/bash
```

The Bamboo version is `6.5.1`.

Comment: did you add `-e` without a value ?

Comment: and your script should begin with `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @LinSel where can I add -e without a value?

Comment: removing `#!/bin/bash` returned the same error

Answer (score 1):

Facing same/similar issue.  I start my Bamboo plan

```
Isolate build -> Docker container -> Docker image: centos
```

I have a single inline script task that returns some data.

```
whoami

ls -la

pwd
```

The output is NOT from the container but from the agent.  I would expect the path to be /home/bamboo as this is where I start when I run the image directly in docker.

```
19-Mar-2020 15:07:41    bamboo
19-Mar-2020 15:07:41    total 0
19-Mar-2020 15:07:41    drwxr-xr-x 2 bamboo bamboo  6 Mar 19 19:07 .
19-Mar-2020 15:07:41    drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   30 Mar 19 19:07 ..
19-Mar-2020 15:07:41    /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/SANDY-JOB1
```

Comment: For my solution I ended up using  "docker run..." in a script tasks. We have all our plans converted and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set an environment variable on a Bamboo Docker Runner image (isolation build as opposed to using the agent environment), you have three options:

1. Modify the base image you are using as the build container to include the environment options.  This is done by using a Dockerfile (example below) and then saving the image in a repository that Bamboo has access to (e.g. Docker Hub):

   ```
   FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk
   ENV foo=bar
   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myRuntime.dll"]
   ```
2. Use tasks in the job to set the needed environment variables via a script.
3. Use the Agent Environment and as the first task run a Docker task with the build image and the appropriate environment variable flags passed in.

Comment: I am using Isolate build as described here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/docker-runner-946020207.html where is it possible to add the environment flag?